# Reemplazar los <li> y </li> en una cadena String por javascript?

Tags: javascript

Solicito su apoyo para reemplazar los `<li>` y `</li>`  en una cadena String por javascript?

Reemplzar por `<li>` por `''` y `</li>` por `<br>`

ejem:

```
<li>No aplica p.</li>
<li>No aplica p2.</li>
<li>No aplica p3.</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que usar la funcion `replace` asi:

```js
var cadena = '<li>No aplica p.</li><li>No aplica p2.</li><li>No aplica p3.</li>';

var nuevaCadena = cadena.replace(/<li>/g, "").replace(/<\/li>/g, "<br>");

console.log(nuevaCadena);
```